# String creation in java

Tags: java, string

In java String can be created by using new operator or by using + and +=. So, does all these string creation techniques check whether the string already exist in the string pool. If they dint then which String creation technique will check the pool.

Comment: What do you mean? If two String have the same value?

Comment: if it checks then why is this statement returning false. String hello = "Hello", lo = "lo"; System.out.print((hello == ("Hel"+lo)) + " ");

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No they don't.

Simple example :

```
    String s = new String("hell");
    String hello = "hello";
    s += 'o';
    System.out.println(hello == hello.intern()); //True
    System.out.println(s == s.intern());         //False
    System.out.println(s == hello);              //False
    System.out.println(s.intern() == hello);     //True
    //To sum up : s != s.intern() == hello.intern() == hello
```

[This code on ideone](http://ideone.com/sZ6TR)

Here the new version of "s" isn't the internal version of "hello"

If you want to have the pool version of a specific string, you can use the `intern()` method (just as I did above). This way you're sure to have the same reference.

---

**Resources :**

- [Javadoc : `String.intern()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29) (you might think that the link points to `valueOf(double)`, but the `intern()` method is right after ;) )

Comment: You mean to say that only intern() will check whether the string exist in pool.

Comment: String hello = "Hello";
        System.out.print((hello == ("Hel"+"lo"))); //i dint use intern but it returns true.

Comment: @sadananda salam, here the compiler saw that it could be simplified as "Hello" directly, so "Hel"+"lo" == "Hello" at compile time.

Answer (score 3):

Only string constants and literals are automatically interned.  If you're concatenating or otherwise creating strings, you need to actually call the intern() method.  See http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern().

Comment: you said concatenating and creating strings. is it string object concatenation or string constant/literal concatenation or both.  String creation can be done by new, +, += operator. do i need to use intern for all the 3 operators.

Comment: @sadananda, my intent was actually just to cite examples.  The **only** case where intern() is implicit is in the two cases (really just one, since they're the same) I mentioned of "string constants" and "string literals".  All other forms of obtaining strings (+, +=, StringBuilder.toString(), etc.) will be new instances and not interned.